# IIS with localhost webapp login .dll base weird problem

Tags: http, iis, dll, localhost, tomcat8

I have a web application set up with tomcat on localhost. i use IIS. when i try to log in the app loads and nothing happens. I have determined that there is a problem between the .dll database and IIS. What is interesting, when in the .properties file I change the path to IIS of a friend who has exactly the same database uploaded in his IIS application, everything works fine. Another interesting thing is that when I click on "Browse :80" everything looks ok and the database loads, but there is no response from the application level. I checked some settings related to ISAPI and CGI and added permissions to the user, but nothing helped. Can anyone suspect what the problem is?

ISS path in properties file: xyz.iis.url=http://localhost:80/xyz/KDISAPIService.dll/soap/IIKP

Comment: You will have to describe clearly how you configure Java on IIS. Usually people just need to test their Java app on Tomcat, and then integrate Tomcat with IIS with HttpPlatformHandler, https://halfblood.pro/the-rough-history-of-iis-httpplatformhandler/

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.